# Trigger log-write in Foreach loop?

Tags: powershell, scripting

So I've got the below loop, The last item : Log-Write     just is not kicked off.

```
Foreach ($Manager in $Managers) {
    $time = (Get-Date).ToString('T')
    New-bhReportToGroup
    Get-bhDReports
    Set-bhRTGmembers
    Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue "========================[ $time ]==============================="
}
```

I didn't crowd everything with all the code because I'm betting it's not important with this. But I have multiple Log-Write calls in the various functions that all work. The goal was to introduce a divider between each loop iteration within the log file.

This is beautiful with `$Global:DebugPreference` set to continue, but nothing hits the log file.

Thanks!

EDIT

The Log-Write function does this:

```
Function Log-Write {
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]  

  

  Param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$LogPath, [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$LineValue)

  

  Process{

    Add-Content -Path $LogPath -Value $LineValue

  

    #Write to screen for debug mode

    Write-Debug $LineValue

  }

}
```

Comment: What is `Log-Write`?

Comment: Sorry Bill_Stewart, I pasted teh function above for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

The most general way to redirect output to the log is redirection.  You can read about redirection [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.1).

If this doesn't work for you,  you can use the Out-File cmdlet.  You can read the help file [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.1).  The simplest way to use Out-file is in a pipeline.

```
"This gets sent to a logfile" | Out-File myfile.log
```